# Exposing docker container to outside service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is not dockerized version:
currently I am having service that is using two addresses to communicate with outside world. First address is a tcp `0.0.0.0:5000` and this is web service so when I just type `http://localhost:5000` or any other address it works.
Other is an udp service that binds to address as listener and send messages to outside service for example:

UDP client receives messages on ip endpoints `0.0.0.0:8000` and sends them on for example localhost:8001 (there is a service on host that receives and resend messages)

So it works without a docker.

Now a problem, I have turn it to docker image and component but have a problem to send messages through udp to service on docker host.

So I tried redirecting port in docker compose using:

```yaml
    version: '3.9'

        services:
          app:
            build: 
              context: ../../
              dockerfile: /app/_docker/Dockerfile
            container_name: app
            restart: always
            ports:
               - 5000:5000 #for web 
               - 8000:8000 #for udp receiver
               - 8001:8001 #for udp sender
```

Now web works (I have checked) and UDP receiver probably works because it binds to broadcast address, but I am unable to send message to outside host (UDP receiver on host is also binded to `0.0.0.0:8001` and sending message to remote ip - that means it should be ip of my docker image).

I tired also:

```yaml
    services:
      app:
        build: 
          context: ../../
          dockerfile: /app/_docker/Dockerfile
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        network_mode: "host"
```

But now nothing works (I type `localhost:5000` and nothing).

So is that type of communication is possible and if yes what am I doing wrong?

Also I am using windows but this will be deployed on linux as well, and can't dockerize service on host that response to my UDP requests.

EDIT:

Maybyu
I have changed port forwarding to look like:

```
   - 5000:5000
   - 50005:50005/udp
   - 50000:50000/udp
```

And I noticed if I type http://172.21.232.161:5000/ (as 172.21.232.161 is my HyperV interface address or docker0 in case of linux) it works for web

I have inspected my docker container for gateway and container ip and it looks like:

```
"Gateway": "172.31.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.31.0.4"
```

So I may expect when bind UDP receiver on 172.21.232.161:8000 on host computer and send frame from docker to 172.31.0.1:8000 on UDP it should work. But it does not.
So what should I put to sending endpoint (172.31.0.1:8000) to receive message on host?

Comment: from inside docker you are sending message outside, right? or you sending on same app, use app:8000 if on same app

Comment: You should use the bridged network mode in order to reach hosts in the real world.

Comment: For udp receiver you should use `8000:8000/udp`, udp sender doesnot need to bind port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many battles, answer was simple .. if my windows host has external ip for example 10.0.0.4 container will send messages on 10.0.0.4:8000 (or host.docker.internal) and receive messages on 0.0.0.0:8001